# Ciclo para promedios con Pandas, frecuencia cada 5 minutos

Tags: python, sql, pandas, numpy

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola, tengo este df. Estoy intentando obtener valores promedio asignados a cada hora de datos medidos con una frecuencia de 5 minutos. Así es como cargo el df desde MySQL:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode
import pandas as pd
def data_base_connection(user,password,host,database):
config = {
    'user': user,
    'password': password,
    'host': host,
    'database': database,
    'raise_on_warnings': True,
}

try:
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
    return cnx
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
        print("Something is wrong with your user name or password")
    elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
        print("Database does not exist")
    else:
        print(err)

   cnx=data_base_connection("root","cigefi","127.0.0.1","a_siquirres")

   # Create cursor
   cursor=cnx.cursor()
   query1=("select fh,tc10, tc20, tc30, hr10, hr20, hr30, prec10, prec20,        prec30, vs10, vu10, dir10, desU10, vmax10, vs20, vu20, dir20, desU20, vmax20, vs30, vu30, dir30, desU30, vmax30, tsuelo, vw, paus from siqoriginal")
   # Excute Query

   cursor.execute(query1)

   rows = cursor.fetchall()
   df = pd.DataFrame([[ij for ij in i] for i in rows])  # Se cargan los       rows pandas, de la consulta que se hizo.
   df.rename(columns={0: 'fh', 1: 'tc10', 2:'tc20', 3:'tc30', 4: 'hr10', 5: 'hr20', 6: 'hr30', 7:'prec10', 8: 'prec20', 9: 'prec30', 10: 'vs10', 11: 'vu10', 12: 'dir10', 13: 'desU10', 14: 'vmax10', 15: 'vs20', 16: 'vu20', 17: 'dir20', 18: 'desU20', 19: 'vmax20', 20: 'vs30', 21: 'vu30', 22: 'dir30', 23: 'desU30', 24: 'vmax30', 25: 'tsuelo', 26: 'vw', 27: 'paus'}, inplace=True)
   df['fh'] = pd.to_datetime(df['fh'], infer_datetime_format=True)  #     Convertir datetime.

df
```

Luego intento usar gruopby de Pandas para hacer los promedios horarios:

```
medias = df.groupby([df.index.year,
                 df.index.month,
                 df.index.hour])['tc10'].mean()

medias.index.names = ["Año", "Mes", "Hora"]
```

Sin embargo, me tira este error:

> 'RangeIndex' object has no attribute 'year'.

Quisiera saber si hay algún problema con la frecuencia de los datos, y si hay alguna manera en la que pueda asignar un promedio horario a cada hora. Como un for, o algún módulo de numpy o pandas.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: El índice de tu Dataframe no es de tipo `DatetimeIndex`, la columna `fh` no es el índice de tu `DataFrame`, el índice es un `RangeIndex` (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...) como muestra el error. O haces que esta columna sea el índice o agrupas sobre ella en vez de sobre `df.index`

Comment: Ok! Muchísimas gracias!